# Can Shiny Server Serve a HTML page without ui.R or server.R

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I have a HTML doc created with RStudio's RMarkdown.
Is there a way I can serve that page in Shiny server without
going through attaching it into **ui.R** or **server.R**?

If so, how can I go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the documentation for [dynamic / interactive Markdown documents](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_shiny.html).

I had long converted all my apps from using `ui.R` and `server.R` to using a single `app.R`; I now convert them to being `index.Rmd` as having [flexdashboard](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/) with [shiny](http://shiny.rstudio.com/) is the best thing yet.

Comment: Thanks. With Shiny app one would usually copy the directory or soft link  to `/srv/shiny-server` with your approach how should we do it?

Comment: That is where the server expects its content, and that remains unchanged.

Comment: That's a good shout re [flexdashboard](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/) and [shiny](http://shiny.rstudio.com/) @DirkEddelbuettel, that's my weekend sorted!